# Proper participle

Tags: grammar

我经验过 还是 我经验了?
since guo also means experience I am wondering if one of these is the right way, actually i can't remember exactly how to use guo.

is it redundant to use guo when already using jing yan?

Answer (score 1):

both possible，see below, 经验 is mostly used as noun, although as pointed out by OP it can function as verb, "to experience" most often is 经历, e.g. 亲身经历过,  bkrs: most examples for use as noun, only one for verb among 7 pages of examples: **我经验了那个**,现代汉语词典 does have 经验 as verb:经验(2)经历（１）：这样的事，**我从来没经验过**，iciba in fact only translates 经验 as noun

Answer (score 0):

经验 is mostly used as a noun, the common words for the verb "to experience" is  "经历" or "体验" in Chinese

The verb particle **过** denotes the "**experience**" aspect of the verb

The verb particle **了** denotes the "**completion**" aspect of the verb

- 经历風浪 = [going through crisis] (no indication of tense, actually Chinese words don't have tense)
- 经历**过**風浪 means [**had experienced** going through crisis]
- 经历**了**風浪 indicates [the verb experience in "experience crisis" **is completed**]

In 去经历風浪 (go experience crisis), neither 'go' nor 'experience' is completed

In 去**了**经历風浪, the verb 'go' is completed

In 去经历風浪**了**, the verb phrase 'go experience crisis' is completed